# Factorial number divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What's the biggest number $n$ such that $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot 2016\cdot 2017$ is divisible by $7^n$.
I thought answer is $288$, because $2016$ is divisible by $7$ and it yields $288$, but answer seems to be $334$ and I'm not sure why.

Comment: This is a well-known problem. You may simply look at the Legendre's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Comment: Hint: consider the factors of each number, you want to count how many $7$'s you find in the factors of $2017!$. Let's take the number $49$, for example, it's $49=7^2$ so that actually adds two $7$'s, instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Use De Polygnac formula
 It states
 Power of a prime,p in $n!=[\frac n p] + [\frac n {p^2}] +... $

Till $p^m<=n$ , $m \in \mathbb Z$

Now here n=2017 and p=7

$[\frac {2017} 7 ]+[\frac {2017} {7^2}]+[\frac {2017} {7^3}]$

$=288+41+5$

$=334$