# Smallest factorial having $n$ as a factor.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For a positive integer $n$, I am trying to find a describtion for the smallest integer $m$ such that $n$ is a factor for $m !$. When $n$ is prime number then $n=m$. If the standered factorization of $n$ as product of prime numbers is given by $n=p^{a_1}_1 p^{a_2}_{2} ...   p^{a_t}_{t}$ then $m\le max \{p^{a_1}_1, p^{a_2}_{2}, ...  , p^{a_t}_{t}\}$. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002034

Comment: It might help to consider the prime factorization $m!$ If $p_1 < p_2 < .......... < p_w < m$ and $p_w$ is the largest prime less than  or equal to $m$ then $m! = p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}..... p_w^{\beta_w}$.   So we just need $m$ to be the number where all the $\beta_k$ greater or equal to  $a_k$.  But what are the $\beta_k$ equal to? So figure out how to express the $\beta_k$ and figure out how you can have the least necessary $\beta_k$ and what least $m$ would that produce.

Comment: It may help to note $21! =1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12*13*14*15*16*17*18*19*20*21=2^{10}*1*1*3*2*5*3*7*4*9*5*11*6*13*7*15*8*17*9*19*10*21=2^{10+5}1*1*3*1*5*3*7*2*9*5*11*3*13*7*15*4*17*9*19*5*21=2^{10+5+2}*1*1*3*1*5*3*7*1*9*5*11*13*7*15*2*17*9*19*5*21=2^{10+5+2+1}*1*1*3*1*5*3*7*1*9*5*11*13*7*15*1*17*9*19*5*21=2^{18}3^7*1*1*1*1*5*1*7*1*3*5*11*13*7*5*1*17*3*19*5*7=2^{18}3^{7+2}*1*1*1*1*5*1*7*1*1*5*11*13*7*5*1*17*1*19*5*7=2^{18}3^{9}5^{4} *1*1*1*1*1*1*7*1*1*1*11*1*13*7*1*1*17*1*19*1*7=2^{18}3^{9}5^47^3*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*1*11*1*13*1*1*1*17*1*19*1*1=2^{18}3^{9}5^47^3*11*13*17*1*19$

Comment: Say the answer is given by $f(n) $. Hint: 1)Determine $f( p^a)$ for prime $p$.  2) Show that for primes $p_i $, $ f( \prod p_i ^{a_i} ) = \max ( f(p_i ^{a_i } ) $.

Comment: Legendre's method for determining highest power of a prime in a factorial.Here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149186/factorial-number-divisibility/3427654

Comment: First of all I would like to thank all for their suggestions.  I am aware of Legendre's method and cann't see how it might be applied in this case. Even the suggestion to compute $ f(p^a)$ then to  ... . I am afraid that doesnt work either. As an example if we let $n=40=2^3*5$ then $f(40)= 5$ but $f(2^3)=4$.

Comment: @Paul but [Calvin Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54563/calvin-lin) said to take the maximum and $\max(f(2^3),f(5))$ is $\max(4,5) = 5$. So that answer really is right. I vote for  [Calvin Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54563/calvin-lin).

Comment: Agree. Any hint how to compute  $f(p^{a})$?

Comment: To determine $f(p^\alpha)$ , you only need to add the $p$-valuations of the multiples of $p$ upto at most $\alpha\cdot p$ until the sum is at least $\alpha$.